# Add To The Current Background Image Via JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, background-image

I created a layerd image in Photoshop. I would like to add one layer of that image to the background of a div every second. This is the code I am currently working with, but it's not working. Any help is appreaciated.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

import img1 from '../../img/INTRO/1.png';
import img2 from '../../img/INTRO/2.png';
import img2 from '../../img/INTRO/3.png';

function IntroMain() {
    const imageDiv = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        let arrOfImages = new Array(),
            i = 0,
            interval = 700,
            currentBG;
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('set bg img now');
            imageDiv.current.style.backgroundImage = `url(${img3})`;
            imageDiv.current.style.backgroundSize = `cover`;
            currentBG = `url(${img1}), `;
        }, interval);
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('set bg 2 img now');
            imageDiv.current.style.backgroundImage = `url(${img2})`;
            imageDiv.current.style.backgroundSize = `cover, cover`;
        }, interval * 2);
    });

    return <div id="image-div" ref={imageDiv}></div>;
}

export default IntroMain;
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve. What does *add to the current background image* mean? Do you want to cycle through a pool of background images and be able to add to or remove images from that pool?

Comment: Basically. I created a layered image in photoshop. I want to build up an image (whether it be an <img> or a background-image layer by layer with setTimeout. Using position absolute has made it a nightmare to align other elements.

Comment: I see, so the images have transparency and you want to place them on top of each other?

Comment: Exactly yeah that’s what I’m looking to do

Comment: Okay I'll try to answer with an example of how you could adapt your code to achieve that. Are you familiar with react hooks or do you use class based components only?

Comment: I use hooks now all the time.

Comment: I appreciate it a lot

Comment: See my answer and comment if you feel like something is missing. I'll add it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting multiple background images on a `div` you can use the css property `background-image`. It looks like:

```
background-image: url('/first/image.jpg'), url('second/image.jpg') ...;
```

Your app can hold the image urls and the display state in an array that you can update through user interaction or based on time. You can then dynamically build the css property value from the image urls to display. Example App:

```
const IMAGES = [
  // this could be real paths instead
  /* red */ "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8z8BQDwAEhQGAhKmMIQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==",
  /* green */ "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+M9QDwADhgGAWjR9awAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==",
  /* blue */ "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNkYPhfDwAChwGA60e6kgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
];

const Toggle = ({ layers, onToggle }) => {
  // this component is just for demonstration of dynamically toggling images
  return layers.map((layer, idx) => (
    <button
      key={layer.url}
      onClick={() => onToggle(idx)}
      style={{ background: layer.display ? `url(${layer.url})` : "none" }}
    >{`Toggle Layer ${idx}`}</button>
  ));
};

const Layers = () => {
  // we initialize the array from the image urls and set every layer to display: false
  const [layers, setLayers] = useState(() =>
    IMAGES.map(url => ({ url, display: false }))
  );

  // this method toggles the display state of the layer at idx
  const handleToggleLayer = idx =>
    setLayers(current =>
      current.map((layer, i) =>
        i === idx ? { ...layer, display: !layer.display } : layer
      )
    );

  return (
    <div>
      <Toggle layers={layers} onToggle={handleToggleLayer} />
      <div
        className="layers"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: layers
            .filter(layer => layer.display)
            .map(layer => `url(${layer.url})`)
            .join(", ")
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Live Demo:

[image: Edit keen-wilbur-t6yim]

Note that the first image listed will be on top (the front-most).

The example uses [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) to wrap the image paths in `url( ... )` and [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to join them.